# Finding the distance from a corner of a cube to the midpoint of an edge

Tags: geometry

I am struggling with the following problem:

"The squares $ABCD$ and $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ are opposite sides of a cube, connected by the edges $AA_1$, $BB_1$, $CC_1$, and $DD_1$. The length of the cube's edge is $a$ units. Determine and state the distance from corner $A$ to the midpoint of edge $B_1C_1$."

I have attempted to solve this by drawing a diagram and using the Pythagorean theorem, but I keep getting stuck. I believe the solution involves finding the midpoint of edge $B_1C_1$ and then using the distance formula to find the distance between the midpoint and corner $A$, but I'm not sure how to find the midpoint.

Any help or guidance on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let's call $M$ the midpoint of $B_1C_1$. You can check on your diagram that connecting the points $A$, $A_1$, and $M$ form a right triangle with its right angle between edges $AA_1$ and $A_1M$ and its hypotenuse as the edge $AM$. We want to find the length of this hypotenuse, as this will give us the distance between $A$ and $M$. Thus, by the pythagorean theorem, we only need to know the lengths of the edged $AA_1$ (which we are given to be $a$) and $A_1M$. Finding the length of $A_1M$ is another application of the pythagorean theorem, and we can combine all this information to get the length of $AM$ and complete the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Perhaps you can show us the diagram you've drawn? Let $M_1$ be the midpoint of $B_1C_1$. Observe that $$\angle AA_1B_1=\angle AB_1M_1=\frac{\pi}2\,.$$ Using Pythagorean theorem, we have $${AA_1}^2+{A_1B_1}^2={AB_1}^2\quad \text{and}\quad {AB_1}^2+{B_1M_1}^2={AM_1}^2\,.$$ Therefore, $${AM_1}=\sqrt{{AA_1}^2+{A_1B_1}^2+{B_1M_1}^2}=\frac{3a}{2}\,.$$

Comment: Answer should be 3a/2.

Comment: My typo. Thanks for pointing that out.